# Display multiple items in one screen in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I display an item on the right in my `recyclerView` as shown in the images?

Condition: if I have two or more items in the list, I want to display list like in the screens(**You can see the first element and part of the second**)

[image]

[image]

With the `ItemDecoration` mb?

Updated my code in xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_42"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="21dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_13"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_38"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_13"
        android:progress="3" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/connectionLogoView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_24"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_24"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_14"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_9"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_12"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_9"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            tools:background="@color/blue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/providerNameView"
            style="@style/Text16BlackRegular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/connectionLogoView"
            tools:text="HSBC Bank UK" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
            style="@style/Text14BlueMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_12"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="3:25" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Now i get next screens:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post what have you tried.

Comment: @Ashish added xml code, but in this xml, i can see only 1 item from `recyclerView`

Comment: Do you want to show horizontal View of RecyclerView

Comment: I did not understand your question. Could you please more explain it?

Comment: @Ashish I'm already displaying horizontal. I want to display in `recyclerView` if two items in the list, I saw part of the second item as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @TariqulIslam updated, maybe now it will be clear
if not, let me know, I'll try to update

Answer (score 2):

programmatically find the screen width and set the width of the root layout of all items as say eg 60% of found width. this should partially show your second item.

You can find the screen width as follows:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Use this width, and in bindviewholder, set the root layout width of your item as 60% of the found width (you can change 60 to whatever suits you). **NOTE: Make sure to use RecyclerView layout params when setting the width as the item's root layout will have the recyclerview as it's parent layout, not doing so will throw class cast exception**

Comment: "wrap the item's layout in a ConstraintLayout" u mean xml code of my item in `recyclerView`?

Comment: Yes xml... And add a guideline vertical orientation with guide percent u need eg 0.6 for 60% and then follow what i said for the original root view

Comment: Updated question, can u check please my xml?

Comment: Checked on my pc, yea it will have the same issue always as the parent will have width match parent... I am an idiot for not figuring that part, my bad... removed the alternate approach, only the first approach will work for you

Comment: strange that I cannot establish wrap_content for ConstraintLayout

Comment: if you do that, the guideline wont work that's why it cant be used. programmatic approach is the one i have always used. this suddenly popped in my head so i was like yeah why havent i done this, lol.... now i know why :D anyway approach one is tried and tested. Do not forget to add margin right to your root cardview.

Comment: i write next fun: 
`fun findScreenWidth(): Int {
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        activity?.windowManager?.defaultDisplay?.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        return width
    }
```
and tried to set width: `recyclerView?.width = findScreenWidth()`
but i can t do it because width is val

Comment: Dont set recycler views width, set the viewholder root views width... Inside onBindViewholder. Also i m not a kotlin dev so can't help with ur issue...

Comment: but i can't set width for my RelativeLayout in viewholder, because it s `val` (read-only)

Comment: I cant help with a workaround for the val issue bro, not a kotlin dev.... it's the only way i know to make this. Alternate approach would be to keep a horizontal scroll view and programmatically add cards with the calculated width to this view

Comment: I solved the previous problem, but my card is not centered as in the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198642/discussion-between-kushan-and-morozov).